# Какое отношение между классами

Tags: ооп, uml

Пример абстрактный, есть два класса: Main - он что-то делает свое, и результат сохраняет в базу данных, вызывая метод с параметрами из класса DBManager, который, в свою очередь тоже работает полностью обособленно от класса Main.

Так вот, какое отношение будет между классами Main и DBManager? (композиция, агрегация), желательно объяснить почему именно оно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это зависит от времени жизни DBManager относительно Main. Если при уничтожении Main будет уничтожен и DBManager, то речь идет о композиции, в противном случае - об агрегации.